# Difference Between Placing `$match` Before or After `$unwind` in MongoDB Aggregate for My BooksDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, match, aggregate, unwind

Hello MongoDB community,

I am trying to understand the difference in the results and performance implications between two aggregate queries in MongoDB. Both queries aim to count the number of books each author has written, but they place the `$match` stage at different points in the pipeline.

Here's the first query:

```
db.books.aggregate([
  { $match: { 'authors': { $ne: '' } } },
  { $unwind: '$authors' },
  { $group: { _id: '$authors', numBooks: { $count: {} } } },
  { $sort: { 'numBooks': -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 }
])
```

And here is the second one:

```
db.books.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$authors' },
  { $match: { 'authors': { $ne: '' } } },
  { $group: { _id: '$authors', numBooks: { $count: {} } } },
  { $sort: { 'numBooks': -1 } },
  { $limit: 5 }
])
```

The first query filters out documents where the 'authors' array is empty before unwinding the array, while the second one unwinds the 'authors' array first and then filters out any documents where the 'authors' field is an empty string.

[output of my queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv1O9.png)

Shouldn't the output of both queries be identical? If I $unwind the array and subsequently filter out the non-empty sets or if I first eliminate empty arrays and then proceed with the $unwind operation on the remaining documents with authors, the final result should be the same, right?

[The schema of my database is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WAiK.png)

I'm pondering this because the 'authors' field is an array of strings, and it seems like regardless of whether the $match stage comes before or after the $unwind stage, the operations should theoretically filter out the same data. Yet, does the sequence of $unwind and $match somehow influence the outcome in ways I'm not accounting for? Could someone explain the difference between these two approaches?

Thanks

I've thoroughly reviewed the database and individually examined the entries for movies by the varying authors, but I haven't found anything unusual. And I still don't understand why it's yielding different results.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Post your current output and example documents as code/text instead of images.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Instead a sequence of `$unwind, $match, $group` you may use [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) - often you can get the same result with less code and better performance.

Comment: @aneroid Thank you for your answers, I had trouble with the format in my initial question, I apologize for that. From now on, I will provide the information in the text format as you suggested.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will keep that in mind for my future queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between matching first & then unwinding vs unwinding first and then matching is the effect of *`$match` with arrays* vs *$match with strings*.

**1.** In the case of `$match` first, `{ 'authors': { $ne: '' } }` - if *any of the authors in the array* is an empty string, then **it excludes the whole document**, not just that one item in the array.

So when you match first, all the `books` which have at least one empty string as an author get eliminated. And then there are fewer books to `$unwind` in the next stage.

Here's a [shorter example reproducing the behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

Collection:

```js
[
  { _id: 1, names: [ "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" ] },
  { _id: 2, names: [ "David", "", "Elle" ] },
]
```

Check which documents match

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { "names": { $ne: "" } }
  }
])
```

Result is the whole 1st document and no parts of the 2nd:

```js
[
  { _id: 1, names: [ "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" ] },
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Q72J0TQ1cl)

**2.** When you `$unwind` first and then `$match`, you're matching a string with a string (not an array of strings) - so it would exclude just that one unwound 'row'/record - which means the other `id=2` records for 'David' and 'Elle' remain after the stage.

Comment: Now I understand. Due to the vast size of the database, I initially overlooked this detail, but upon closer inspection and specifically reviewing authors with a declining number of books, I've noticed that some entries contain an empty string (""). This would indeed disqualify those books from the aggregation. Thank you very much for the thorough and insightful explanation – it was extremely helpful!